# How to delete lines with specific text in multiple files and get output with grep

Tags: shell, grep

I am trying to delete all lines containing "Cl" in 50 files in a directory:
and send the modified files in a subdirectory no_cl

`grep -vE "Cl" *.pdb > no_cl/$*.pdb`

however, this does not work,

How can I use wildcards with this statement?

Answer (score 0):

**`find -name "*.pdb" -type f -print0 | xargs -t -n1 -0 -I % sh -c 'grep -vE Cl % > no_cl/%'`**

Discussion:

You can use a shell loop depending on your shell, but with either `find` and `xargs` you can turn a list of files from standard input into multiple `grep` invocations.

`/bin/ls *.pdb | xargs -t -n 1 -I % sh -c 'grep -vE Cl % > no_cl/%'`

Use `/bin/ls` (prevents using any aliases for `ls`) to get `*.pdb`, pipe to `xargs` which uses `-n 1` to turn each input token into a command.  `-I %` tells xargs to replace `%` with the input token.  Xargs is then used to execute `sh -c 'grep -vE Cl % > no_cl/%`.   `-t` echos each command that xargs executes.

This breaks if any of the file names have spaces in them.  Etc etc [read this for more "don't use ls" discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22229/xargs-with-stdin-stdout-redirection).

Or: `find -name "*.pdb" -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -vE Cl < "{}" > "no_cl/{}"' \;`
... which might also break with spaces.  And the `find -exec` syntax is weird.

So, best of both worlds.  Use `find` for a null terminated file list, and `xargs` for executing `grep` for each file:

**`find -name "*.pdb" -type f -print0 | xargs -t -n1 -0 -I % sh -c 'grep -vE Cl % > no_cl/%'`**

`-print0` tells `find` to use null termination, and `-0` tells `xargs` to expect it.